# Sent SMS count is not getting saved in android

Tags: android, sms

Hi everyone I'm trying to get sent and received SMS count. I'm trying to save count in database on sending and receiving a SMS. I'm having problem in saving sent count. Plz help me solving it. Thanks in advance.

SentCount.java

```
public class SentCount extends Service {

public Context context;
private static int initialPos;
private static final String TAG = "SMSContentObserver";
private static final Uri uriSMS = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");



public class content extends ContentObserver{

    public content(Handler handler, Context ctx) {
        super(handler);
        context = ctx;

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange){
        //Context context = this.Context;

        Log.d("onchage", "on cange calld");
        DBConnect dbc = new DBConnect(context);
        int duration=Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor c = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://sms"), null, null, null, null);
        if(c.moveToNext())
        {
            try{
                int leastId = getLastid();
                if(initialPos!=leastId)
                {
                    String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Address"));
                    String date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Date"));
                    String msg = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"));
                    initialPos = leastId;
                    dbc.SaveSentCount(number, date);
                    Log.d("Sent to:", "SMS Sent to:"+number+"  on:"+date+ "  Msg:"+msg);
                }

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.v("Tag", e.getMessage());
            }
        }   
        c.close();
    }

    private int getLastid() {
        ContentResolver con = getContentResolver();
        Cursor c = con.query(uriSMS, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int lastid = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        Log.d("lastid:", "Saved"+lastid );
        c.close();
        return lastid;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return false;
    }

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    content c = new content(new Handler(), context);
    ContentResolver cr = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
    cr.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"), true, c);
    Toast.makeText(this, "The new Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("","Service Startd");

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // For time consuming an long tasks you can launch a new thread here...
   // Toast.makeText(this, " Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {  
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);           

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

}
```

DBConnect.java

```
public class DBConnect extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final String SNUMB = "Number";
private static final String NUMB = "Number";
private static final String SDATE = "Date";
private static final String DATE = "Date";
private Context context;
public DBConnect(Context context) {
    super(context, "SMSLogDB.db", null, 1);
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ReceiveSms(`Number` TEXT, `Date` TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SentSms(`Number` TEXT, `Date` TEXT)");
    Log.d("","ReceiveSmsTable Created");
    Log.d("","SentSmsTable Created");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void SaveReceivCount(String pnum, String date)
{
    try{
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(NUMB, pnum);
    values.put(DATE, date);
    database.insert("ReceiveSms", null, values);
    database.close();
    Log.d("noti:", "Recevd sms insertd");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("SaveReceivCount Exception:", ""+e);
    }
}

public void SaveSentCount(String num, String dte)
{
    try{
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(NUMB, num);
        values.put(DATE, dte);
        database.insert("SentSms", null, values);
        database.close();
        Log.d("noti:", "Sent sms insertd");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("SaveSentCount Exception:", ""+e);
        }
}

public int GetReceivCount()
{
    Context context = null;
    String cdate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM receiveSms WHERE Date = '"+cdate+"'", null);
    Log.d("date_is",cdate);
    int count = c.getCount();
    c.close();
    return count;
} 

public int GetSentCount()
{
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM SentSms",null);
    int count = c.getCount();
    c.close();
    return count;
}

 }
```

Presentcountactivity.java

```
public class PresentCountActivity extends Activity {

DBConnect db = new DBConnect(this);
TextView sent;
TextView received;
TextView t;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.presentcount);

    t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Intent in = getIntent();
    String title = in.getStringExtra("c");
    t.setText(title);

    ReceivdCount();
    SentCount();    
}

public void ReceivdCount()
{
    received = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.received);
    String c = String.valueOf(db.GetReceivCount());
    received.setText(c);

}

public void SentCount()
{
    sent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sent);
    String c = String.valueOf(db.GetSentCount());
    sent.setText(c);
}
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sms.smslog"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.sms.activites.IndexActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.sms.activites.PresentCountActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.sms.activites.OverallCountActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.sms.activites.CountByContactActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.sms.activites.SettingsActivity"></activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.sms.smslog.RecievdCount">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name = "com.sms.smslog.SentCount"
         android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>

<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
</manifest>
```

Logcat is like this:

```
02-28 21:43:06.149: D/onchage(5340): on cange calld 
02-28 21:43:06.677: D/lastid:(5340): Saved5117
02-28 21:43:06.682: D/SaveSentCount Exception:(5340): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 21:43:06.682: D/Sent to:(5340): SMS Sent to:9743834990  on:1393603979999  Msg:hi
02-28 21:43:06.685: W/Trace(5340): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-28 21:43:06.687: W/Trace(5340): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Comment: any error message in logcat?

Comment: I'm getting nullpointerexception. It enters to SaveSentCount method. That Toast is also not getting. Directly gives Exception...

Comment: Post logcat output. and from what you are ssaying it seems that exception is at the the line of Toast. So please ensure that context is not null. @rmn.nish

Comment: Don't paste its image. Please copy the text of logcat and paste here as you do with code. That will be easy to understand.

Comment: Mystic i did as u told. Now i'm not getting any exception. Still count is not saving into database.

Comment: Are you getting `Log.d("noti:", "Sent sms insertd");` line's output in console?

Comment: No. I'm getting exception (Sorry i had told im not getting). I have posted logcat.

Comment: I ran your code and it is not giving me any error, it is giving me output 0

Comment: Yup Mystic its full logcat

Comment: Sent sms count is not saving on sending a sms Kedarnath.. it wil b always 0.

Comment: @rmn.nish, can you upload the code of your androdmanifest.xml ?

Comment: @rmn.nish ok ,I got it. I think you are doing it wrong way. Tell me your requirements please

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48704/discussion-between-kedarnath-and-rmn-nish)

Comment: @rmn.nish, I spent all most 5-6 hours on your code but not able to solve it. Sorry

Comment: Thats k kedarnath.. anyway thanks alot fr trying :(

Comment: @rmn.nish u resolved your issue ?

Comment: @Erum Hannan  nope :(