# Android: Unable to listen for SMS sent

Tags: android

I have written an App to display SMS sent. But my Content Observer is not getting triggered with the following code, when am SMS is sent from default messaging app instead it triggers with URI "content://sms".

```
    SMSSentObserver smsSentObserver = new SMSSentObserver(null, this);
    ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
    contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), true, smsSentObserver);
```

Can some one please tell me why? I have added permission to READ_SMS.

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Basically I need to save the SMS sent on my App. Any help is appreciated.

EDITs:

I tried adding "android.permission.SEND_SMS" as permissions

Here is my SMSSentObserver:

```
public class SMSSentObserver extends ContentObserver {
    private final Context _context;

    public SMSSentObserver(Handler handler, Context context) {
        super(null);
        _context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        saveSentSMS();
        super.onChange(selfChange);
    }

    private void saveSentSMS() {
        Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
        Cursor cur = this._context.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);

        if(null == cur) {
            return;
        }

        if(cur.moveToFirst()) {
            String strProtocol = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("protocol"));
            if(null != strProtocol) { //for sent messages protocol will be null.
                return;
            }

            int type = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("type"));
            if(type == 2) {
                String strSMSBody = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));
                String strPhoneNo = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
                long smsDateTime = cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex("date"));
                String serviceCenter = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("service_center"));
                String strStatus = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("status"));
                String strPerson = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("person"));
                Log.e("Info", "SMS saved");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Also you need permission of SEND SMS `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />`

Comment: Post the code of `SMSSentObserver` class.

Comment: @Kedarnath I added SMSSentObserver code in my post

Comment: `SMSSentObserver smsSentObserver = new SMSSentObserver(null, this);` here instead of null pass new Handler() like this `SMSSentObserver smsSentObserver = new SMSSentObserver( new Handler(), this);` and see what happens.

Comment: @Kedarnath, Still my observer is not getting triggered. I have set new Handler(). Basically I need to get the outgoing messages. I have also tried "content://sms/out", but this is inconsistent.

Comment: Please check this question's code if it helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/q/22099439/3330969

Comment: you welcome, has your problem been solved ?

Comment: @Kedarnath, I have an issue with first sent SMS after that I am able to save all sent SMSes. The code is same as the link you specified. Not sure why first SMS is not saving. The service is getting started again when the app receives the first SMS.